# ¿Como imprimir una cadena JSON dentro de un input con PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

Necesito imprimir una cadena `JSON` desde `PHP` dentro del `value` de un `input`, para luego poder recuperarla con `JavaScript`.

```
<?php
    $array = array(
        "foo" => "bar",
    );
    $json = json_encode($array);
?>

<input id="input" value="<?php echo $json; ?>" />

<script>
  let json = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('input').value);
  console.log(json);
</script>
```

¿Que tendría que hacer para poder imprimir el `JSON` y posteriormente poder recuperarlo desde `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que se necesita es escapar los caracteres `HTML` para evitar que éste se rompa al imprimir el `JSON`. `PHP` cuenta con la función [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php) la cual:

> Convierte caracteres especiales en entidades HTML

### Solución:

```
<?php
    $array = array(
        "foo" => "bar",
    );
    $json = json_encode($array);
?>

<!-- Usamos "htmlspecialchars" para encodear el JSON -->
<input id="input" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($json); ?>" />

<script>
  let json = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('input').value);
  console.log(json);
</script>
```

Comment: :) Al menos nos hubieras dado tiempo para poder responderla.